# Data not updating in Android view pager

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I have a fragment in which I am inserting a tab layout with view pager. The issue is my adapter doesn't update the data when I am getting data in my onSuccess method from the server. It gets initialized before my onSuccess method is called. How can I tell my adapter to re-consider my data? I have tried `notifyDataSetChanged()` but it doesn't work.

**My Fragment**

```
public class CinemaFragmentLandingPage extends BaseHomeFragment implements View.OnClickListener, TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener, CinemasContract.View {

private CinemasContract.Presenter mPresenterCinemas;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

private TabLayout mTabLayout;

private CinemaFragmentTabAdapter mCinemaTabAdapter;

private List<CinemasModel> mDataCinemas;

public static CinemaFragmentLandingPage newInstance() {
    return new CinemaFragmentLandingPage();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cinema_landing, container, false);

    mDataCinemas = new ArrayList<>();

    mPresenterCinemas.getCinemas();

    initViews(rootView);

    return rootView;
}

private void initViews(View rootView) {
    mTabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.cinemas)));

    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.films)));

    mViewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mCinemaTabAdapter = new CinemaFragmentTabAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager(), 2, mDataCinemas);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCinemaTabAdapter);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));

    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}

@Override
public void setLoading(boolean isActive) {
    mHomeActivity.setLoadingDialog(isActive);
}

@Override
public void showGetCinemasSuccess(List<CinemasModel> cinemasModels) {
    setLoading(false);
    mDataCinemas = cinemasModels;
    mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    mViewPager.getAdapter().getItemPosition(0);
}

@Override
public void showGetCinemasFail(int errorCode) {
    setLoading(false);
}

@Override
public void setPresenter(CinemasContract.Presenter presenter) {
    mPresenterCinemas = Preconditions.checkNotNull(presenter);
}
```

}

**My Adapter**

```
public class CinemaFragmentTabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private int mNumOfTabs;

private ArrayList<CinemasModel> mCinemasData;

public CinemaFragmentTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs, List<CinemasModel> cinemasData) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    this.mCinemasData = new ArrayList<CinemasModel>();
    this.mCinemasData.addAll(cinemasData);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment tab = null;
    Bundle cinemasBundle = new Bundle();
    cinemasBundle.putParcelableArrayList("cinemas", this.mCinemasData);

    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            tab = new CinemaFragment();
            tab.setArguments(cinemasBundle);
            break;

        case 1:
            tab = new FilmsFragment();
            tab.setArguments(cinemasBundle);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return tab;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post `onSuccess()` method

Comment: Why don't you setup View pager after showGetCinemasSuccess response

Comment: @Jaymin it simply returns cinemasModel list after a server call.

Comment: @JayThummar It would be fine If I do so... But if my data is updated somehow and I have to notify my adapter about that how to do so?

Comment: @Naila, set list in the adapter when you have updated data and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly define constructor in your pojo class, Like..

```
  public CinemasModel(String title, String description, String imageUrl, String author, String url) {

        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.author = author;
        this.url = url;
    }
```

Then update this code.

```
 CinemasModel cinemas= new CinemasModel(title, description, url, imageUrl, author);

 mDataCinemas.add(cinemas);
 System.out.println("mDataCinemas size = " + mDataCinemas.size());

 mCinemaTabAdapter = new inemaFragmentTabAdapter(getActivity(), mDataCinemas);
 mViewPager.setAdapter(mCinemaTabAdapter );
 mCinemaTabAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note : In pojo class update your parameters instead of title , descriptio, etc.  I hope it will help for you..

Comment: My array list is updating correctly. I have checked with debugging.

Comment: Return arraylist  mCinemasData.size()  in your adapter getCount() method instead of  mNumOfTabs.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: @Naila  Welcome !

Answer (score 0):

```
mDataCinemas = cinemasModels;
```

to

```
mDataCinemas.clear();
mDataCinemas.addAll(cinemasModels);
```

and the call notifyDataSetChange. I think that will help you

Answer (score 0):

Add a method refresh with one parameter as ArrayList mCinemasData in viewpager adapter, and inside the method add below 2 lines
this.mCinemasData = mCinemasData;
notifyDataSetChanged();
Call the method from onsuccess and let me know what happen?

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: once can you confirm whether data in the Arraylist is updating or not?

I mean their is a chance of getting same data every time.So, Is that might be ur issue can you debug and confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
mCinemaTabAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mCinemaTabAdapter.getItemPosition(0);
```

instead of:

```
mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
mViewPager.getAdapter().getItemPosition(0);
```

Comment: did you try initializing your mCinemaTabAdapter in onSuccess() ?

Comment: If I do so, my data updated on first time only. After that no update

Answer (score 0):

Do This in you code

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapter.getItemPosition(0);
```

It will Help you.

Comment: Where am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make method updateData(ArrayList mCinemasData) in your adapter and on method showGetCinemasSuccess(data) { adapter.updateData(data) }
and notifyDataSetChange after.